# Can we glue femto-cameras to photons?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, reference-frames

I know its not as easy as saying to glue nano-cameras to photons. Please consider the following extract (related to Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle) from the Modern's abc of Chemistry:

> ...to observe the position of the electron accurately, light of appropriately small wavelength should be used. But the photons of radiations of smaller wavelength will have higher momentum ($p=h/\lambda$). *When even a single photon of this light used to observe the position of electron strikes against it, a large amount of momentum will be transferred to the electron at the time of collision*. This will change the velocity of the electron and consequently will result into greater uncertainty in velocity or momentum......

If a single photon of light can transfer a large amount of momentum to a particle of mass like electron, can we create sticky femto-cameras with electron like properties (if possible in future) which can stick to photon?

If it is not possible to create sticky nano-cameras or for any other reasons the glue idea doesn't work, atleast can we spread those non-sticky cameras (of electron mass) over the moving photons, so that they can carry them to long distance? It helps us to know what universe is at the far distance.

I have no idea w.r.t particle physics or relativity or even what photon is, what ever I know is that passage. I know there are more difficulties w.r.t this idea, it may be related to creation of those femto-cameras or associating a sticky property to it or any other. I want this concept to be discussed w.r.t whether it is possible that photons can do the job, if we *have* such femto-cameras.

Sometimes I might have misunderstood, if so pardon me and explain.

Comment: In photon's frame of reference (which doesn't exists) photon itself doesn't exists

Comment: Does the book do not explain about photon anywhere before the passage that you cite? Did you search about "nano" on google?

Comment: Sorry if nano meant some other thing, I just want to be clear with what I mean by nano. I meant nano to be any "very small sized" particle.

Comment: How much small?

Comment: @user31782: As said in question, as small as that of electron.

Comment: "Nano" means of order "$10^{-9}$". The classical electron radius is of order $10^{-15}$. I suspect you have asked this question in "_bad-faith_". If you really mean a camera of size of an electron(or photon) then you should write _Femto-camera_. I am commenting only because I am trying to understand your doubt/question.

Comment: @user31782: I have made correction.

Comment: Even if it was possible to attach something to a photon that is moving at the speed of light, how would you receive a signal from that camera, which would be moving at the speed of light?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2RrOm.png

Answer (score 3):

Photons travel at the speed of light. Nothing with mass can travel at that speed. So cameras are out.

In a larger sense, you are asking "Can I look at the world from the point of view of a photon?" Again the answer is no. It isn't really right to think that photons just travel faster than anything else, but are otherwise similar to you and me.

Your point of view is described by an inertial frame of reference. Inertial means we are ignoring gravity. Things move at a constant speed unless a force acts on them.

Given an object and at time $t_0$, you can find the position and length of the object. You can do the same at time $t_1$, and find the velocity of the object.

Somebody moving with respect to you has a different frame of reference. He finds different times, positions, lengths, and velocities. In particular, he will find your ruler is shorter than you think, and your clock runs slower.

It is tempting to thing that since a photon moves faster than everything else, it finds your ruler is shortened to 0 length, and your clock has slowed to the point that it doesn't move. This is not correct.

There is no inertial frame of reference that moves with a photon. This means a photon cannot make distance and time measurements.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It seems impossible according to your opinion.

Comment: what about 99% of the speed of light?

Comment: @Pedro77 - Yes, 99% of the speed of light is possible. Particles in accelerators reach 99.99...% the speed of light. I don't know how many 9's. In principle, there is no limit to how close you can get. It depends on how much energy you can put into going faster. But you can't reach the speed of light.

Answer (score 3):

> Can we glue nano-cameras to photons?

Photons, like electrons, are, as far as we know, *fundamental* 'things' and, as such, are *simple* with few properties and rules for interacting with other fundamental 'things'.

Nano-cameras and glue are part of the macroscopic world and, as such, are not simple but are complex objects, composed of an **enormous** number of interacting, fundamental things like electrons, photons, etc., with emergent properties that simply cannot be translated to the microscopic world of fundamental particles.

In other words, it's not so much that we don't have the technology, it's more that the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: The question was just to mean that can we fix nano cameras (similar to those of electrons) to photons. I didn't mean to take a macroscopic gum and macroscopic camera and attach them. I know that they are composed of so many interacting fundamental things. I am just trying to ask, if we can have such sticky nano cameras (small sized particles similar to  electrons), which can stick to photons and thus enable us to see the beyond universe. Thank you for the time (+1).

Comment: @Godparticle Photons aren't particles in the sense that you are thinking.  They are not little bits of "something", they are not tiny light bullets.  They have no *material* existence. There's nothing to attach anything to.

Comment: @Godparticle, the concept "camera" is not, *in any conceivable way*, similar to the concept "electron".  To write something like "nano cameras similar to electrons" reveals a profound misunderstanding of both cameras and electrons.

Comment: @garyp: I am really confused. If photons have no material existence, how could they hit electrons.

Comment: It is confusing. Sometimes light acts like a wave. Sometimes it acts like particles, or tiny bullets. The particles are called photons. Richard Feynman has a really good explanation. See this video http://vega.org.uk/video/subseries/8, or volume III of this book http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/

Comment: The word "particle" is a funny thing in physics. I like to think of it (and certain other loosely-defined words) as *metaphors* of what's actually happening, which, with quantum mechanics, often makes no sense to our macroscopically-evolved brains.  The entity "photon" can transfer energy and momentum to another entity, and that transfer happens at a well-defined location.  Transferring energy and momentum from one thing to another at a particular place sounds an awful lot like a "hit" (another metaphor in my lexicon). "Particle" as little bit of something (like a BB) doesn't work.